# Unable to label inside ring pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def autopct_format(values):
    def my_format(pct):
        total = sum(values)
        val = int(round(pct*total/100.0)/1000000)
        if val == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            return '{:.1f}%\n({v:,d})'.format(pct, v=val)
    return my_format

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10),dpi=100,layout="constrained")

ax.axis('equal')

width = 0.3
#Color
A, B, C=[plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens]


#OUTSIDE
cin = [A(0.5),A(0.4),A(0.3),B(0.5),B(0.4),B(0.3),B(0.2),B(0.1), C(0.5),C(0.4),C(0.3)]

Labels_Smalls = ['groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC']
labels = ['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'C.3', 
'C.4', 'C.5']
Sizes_Detail = [4,3,5,6,5,10,5,5,4,6]
Sizes = [12,11,30]

pie2, _ ,junk = ax.pie(Sizes_Detail ,radius=1,
                 labels=labels,labeldistance=0.85, 
                 autopct=autopct_format(Sizes_Detail) ,pctdistance = 1.15,
                 colors=cin)

for ea, eb in zip(pie2, _):
    mang =(ea.theta1 + ea.theta2)/2
    tourner = 360 - mang
    eb.set_rotation(mang+tourner)         # rotate the label by (mean_angle + 270)
    eb.set_va("center")
    eb.set_ha("center")
    
plt.setp(pie2, width=width, edgecolor='white')

#INSIDE
pie, _, junk = ax.pie(Sizes, radius=1-width, 
                autopct=autopct_format(Sizes) ,pctdistance = 0.8,
                colors = [A(0.6), B(0.6), C(0.6)])


plt.setp(pie, width=width, edgecolor='white')
plt.margins(0,0)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=3, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(pie):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(Labels_Smalls[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)
    
for ea, eb in zip(pie, _):
    mang =(ea.theta1 + ea.theta2)/2.  # get mean_angle of the wedge
    #print(mang, eb.get_rotation())
    tourner = 360 - mang
    eb.set_rotation(mang+tourner)         # rotate the label by (mean_angle + 270)
    eb.set_va("center")
    eb.set_ha("center")
```

gives the following output :

[image]

But It does only link the outside pie and not the inside one, so how would I do the same chart but with the arrow linking the inside pie to the bbox ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a z-order to `ax.annotate` to push it on top? E.g. `ax.annotate(..., zorder=3, **kw)`.

Comment: hi @JohanC I did try to pass from `zorder=0` to `zorder=3` but this still give the same output. `zorder` is in `kw` in case u missed it.

Comment: Well, doesn't changing the `zorder` to `3` give you your desired plot? You can multiply `x` and `y` by e.g. `0.9` to let the arrow enter deeper inside the pie. ([Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXmvy.png))

Comment: @JohanC in fact it does work if I delete the last loop `for ea, eb in zip(mypie2, _):` , how can I do if I want to keep it ?

Comment: The newly added code shouldn't have any influence on the annotation arrows.  Why would it?

Comment: @JohanC I've edited my post with the exact reproducible example.  Does this code work as excepted for u ?

Comment: Well, if you suddenly change the radii, you need to adapt things everywhere. Maybe `y = 0.5 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))` (and similar for `x`)? Also, it is really confusing if you start using a variable named `_` without giving it a decent name.